# How to lose keyboard scope anywhere in the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, focus

I have a delegate command which when invoked I want to lose focus on any control which has focus.  I am using MVVM therefore the code in the delegate command's execute has no reference to the UIElements.  I am happy to move focus or use any kind of trick to this - but it needs to be somewhat agnostic to which control has focus.

Don't mind if the solution is in XAML or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using the [`TraversalRequest` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to move the focus to the next control? From the linked page, it:

> Represents a request to move focus to another control.

All you need to get this to work is the currently focused element. Again, from the linked page on MSDN:

```
// Creating a FocusNavigationDirection object and setting it to a 
// local field that contains the direction selected.
FocusNavigationDirection focusDirection = _focusMoveValue;

// MoveFocus takes a TraveralReqest as its argument.
TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);

// Gets the element with keyboard focus.
UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

// Change keyboard focus. 
if (elementWithFocus != null)
{
    elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request);
}
```